# Wrong registration url in slave nodes of SymmetricDS

Tags: java, tomcat, symmetricds

I've recently deployed SymmetricDS tutorial example to my Tomcat 8. I have three `.war` files created from corresponding `.properties` files: corp-000.war, store-001.war and store-002.war. The sync.url in corp-000.properties file is:

```
sync.url=http://localhost:8080/corp-000/sync
```

and in my store-XXX.properties files I have this:

```
registration.url=http://localhost:8080/corp-000/sync
```

For some reason, when started all three of them on Tomcat, the log says:

```
[store-002] - PullService - Failed to connect to the transport: http://localhost:31415/sync/corp-000
[store-002] - PullService - Could not communicate with corp:000:000 at http://localhost:31415/sync/corp-000 because: Connection refused: connect
[store-002] - DefaultOfflineClientListener - Failed to connect to the transport: http://localhost:31415/sync/corp-000
```

But that is the url that was in files by default, and I've changed it to what I've written above!

When I run corp-000 node on Tomcat and start store-XXX node using the command `bin\sym' (this runs embedded jetty server) everything connects and works. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: You'll have to find where this port number 31415 comes from

Comment: As you can see, it's not entirely the matter in the port number, as the other url parts are also switched. It's as if me changing the file did not affect the url for some reason

Comment: Are you sure that some internal default `symmetric-ds.properties` file is not picked up?

Comment: I am quite sure, but get this -- after several hours and several restartions of tomcat I started working. I literally changed nothing -- some kind of magic. Thatnks for your active contribution, I think this question should be closed now.

Comment: You're welcome. You can deleted on your own.